# Query working in SQL client returns no row using PHP and PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am really scratching my head because I am trying to figure out why a query that works perfectly in MySQL Client and returns the proper results, has no effect when feeded by PDO. My query is:

```
SELECT id, title, img 
FROM blog_posts JOIN blog_img 
ON blog_posts.id = blog_img.id_post
WHERE id='1';
```

and my PHP/PDO code is:

```
$query = $this->dbconn->get_db_access()->prepare("SELECT id, title, img 
                                                  FROM blog_posts JOIN blog_img 
                                                  ON blog_posts.id = blog_img.id_post 
                                                  WHERE id=:id");
$query->bindParam(":id", $id);
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

No `PDOException` is thrown and yet the `$result` array is empty. Can anyone come up with an explaination, please? Is there anything I am doing wrong? Is there a way to "check" the "final" SQL code after the binding and before it gets thrown in so that I make sure everything is ok?

Comment: Maybe because there are two different queries? `ON blog_posts.id` vs `ON blog_post.id`

Comment: What is the value of `$id` when the query is run?

Comment: @War10ck actually this code is in a `foreach` so each time `$id` has a different id value, which is correct so it is not 'causing the query to fail.

Comment: Do you have that "blog_post" typo in the actual code?

Comment: @Barmar nope, it's not that, I must have made that typo while manually copying the query... fixing that right now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually executing the prepared statement. You have to execute it before you try to retrieve data.

Try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, img 
FROM blog_posts JOIN blog_img 
ON blog_post.id = blog_img.id_post 
WHERE id=:id";

$stmt = $this->dbconn->get_db_access()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Note that `prepare()` will return a `PDOStatement` object. You then bind the parameter to the PDOStatment object and `execute()` the prepared statement.

Finally you get the result using `fetch()`.